# Nuget and Teamcity Agent not allowed to run this configuration

Tags: teamcity, nuget, teamcity-8.0

I came across an interesting issue. I want to build nuget packages with Teamcity. I did set up the configuration which is really straight forward (Good job JetBrains!)

However I am not able to run it on one of our build agents.

The agent does pass the agent requirements for the configuration, but next to it's name the following is shown: **not allowed to run this configuration**

My question: Why?

On the agent configuration parameters page I have Nuget as possible configurations:

```
teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2.nupkg  D:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.2.8.2.nupkg
teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg    D:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg
```

We have a second build agent which is able to run Nuget Packager configuration. 
The main difference between this two machines is that one is a *Windows 8, version 6.2* machine (not allowed to run this configuration) and the other one is a *Windows 7, version 6.1* (allowed run this configuration)

We are running:

```
TeamCity Enterprise 8.0.5 (build 27692)
```

Any hints and help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most likely the agent is configured to run only explicitly assigned configurations.
Plesase, check the Agents ->  -> "Compatible configurations" tab.

There is a combo box with options "Run all compatible" / "Run assined .. ". Make sure "Run all compatible" is selected

Answer (score 1):

You may not always be in a position to Run all compatible, In that case you can go to Agents--> Particular agent --> comaptible configurations --> Assign configurations --> Search and select the specific Job or build.