# Nuget Command in TeamCity

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, teamcity, nuget-package-restore

I want to learn how I can run `nuget update-package` command as a TeamCity build step to update one package for all the projects in my solution.

I have tried using nuget installer as a step, but it didn't work. It tries to update all the package in solution ( I don't want that ), also the package I want to update comes from a TeamCity repo itself (not Nuget.org).

I have also tried adding a 'Command Line' step, but when I do so, I get that I dont have any compatible agent to run this step

`%teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.2.2.1.nupkg%\tools\nuget.exe update.....`

Is there any other way I can run nuget command, or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nuget and Teamcity Agent not allowed to run this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030483/nuget-and-teamcity-agent-not-allowed-to-run-this-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way I can run nuget command, or am I doing anything wrong here?

You can use the option **Id** and **Source** at your command line, like:

```
nuget.exe update -Id <YourPackageName> -Source <YourTeamCityRepo>
```

With those two options, you can update one package for all projects and update comes from TeamCity repo itself (not Nuget.org).

Check [update command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-update) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah! Tried this, but the problem is.. there is a bug (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6166)  in nuget update command which updates all the projects in the directory not in Solution.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri, Have you tried specify the solution file in the command line? Like `nuget.exe update "<YourSolutionPath>\YourSolution.sln" -Id <YourPackageName> -Source <YourTeamCityRepo>`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that! the update command will update all the projects in the folder. I only want to update projects in my solution.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri, That is strange :(. How about specify the specific packages.config file? Like,`nuget.exe update "<YourPackage.configFilePath>\packages.config" -Id <YourPackageName> -Source <YourTeamCityRepo>`. And you can download the new version nuget in the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) instead of using nuget.exe from nuget package.

Comment: I have more than 30 projects in my solution.. cant write this command for each project :(. Even the latest version has this bug..see the issue I have posted in 1st comment.